# Can one see in VLC whether a video has a variable frame rate?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, framerate

I couldn't see the information in `Media->Codec`:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to see in VLC whether a video has a variable frame rate. There is no built-in feature implementing that functionality. However, it is possible to see in VLC whether a video has a variable frame rate, e.g. with ffmpeg or mediainfo.

[ffmpeg command](https://redd.it/156aykx) from Reddit user [Sufficient-Builder69](https://www.reddit.com/user/Sufficient-Builder69):

```
fmpeg -i in -vf vfrdet -an -f null -
```